# Focus to previous jframe

Tags: java, jframe

I was creating a supermarket billing application.When the user press enter on the product text field a new frame with a table will come. He can select particular product and press enter on the selected row and the previous frame should come with the old values. I tried various tricks but the focus is not coming to the first frame.

```
for(Frame frame : Frame.getFrames()){
    if(frame.getTitle().equals("Welcome")){
    System.out.println("Frame located");
    Welcome w=(Welcome) frame;     
    w.setFields(code, name, rate);
    w.setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Would be better to do it using a modal JDialog or using CardLayout switching main app and product selection panels. See also requestFocus()

Comment: what have you tried?  don't just say "various tricks", tell us what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. toFront() method helps to focus the frame